# How to get source class of static[] array

Tags: java, arrays, static

I want the underlying class from a static array. For example if it says `String[].class` I want to get `String.class`

```
    String[] foo = new String[0];
    System.out.println(foo.getClass());
```

Output

```
class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Class#getComponentType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--):

```
Class<?> type = foo.getClass().getComponentType();
System.out.println(type); // class java.lang.String
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--):

> Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this class does not represent an array class this method returns null.

Comment: And if you're not sure `foo` is an array, you might want to first check [`foo.getClass().isArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--), instead of testing whether `getComponentType()` returns null.